# how add carrierwave image to atom feed rss in rails 3.1

Tags: rss, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave, feed, atom-feed

My question is how output image carrierwave with a rss/atom in rails
3?

I try:

```
atom_feed :language => 'en-US' do |feed|
  feed.title @title
  feed.updated @updated

  @posts.each do |item|
  next if item.created_at.blank?

    feed.entry( item ) do |entry|
     entry.url feed_url(item)
     entry.content item.content, :type => 'html'
      link_to (image_tag item.posted.url(:medium)), feed_url(item)

      # the strftime is needed to work with Google Reader.
      entry.updated(item.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
      entry.author item.user.username
    end
  end
end
```

But I can not see nothing :O

**How can I add link_to (image_tag item.posted.url(:medium)), feed_url(item) to my feed?** Thank you

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this end. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

entry.link href: "#{base_url}#{some_variable.image.url(:medium)}", rel:"enclosure", type:"image/jpeg"

and in a helper

def base_url 
  request.protocol + request.host_with_port 
end